# Working plugin code breaks admin

Tags: plugins

I would appreciate any criticism for the big chunk of code below. What I'm trying to do is query a set of custom posts and return them in a table based on custom fields. It works ... the table is being generated, the right posts are being returned, but after executing a query, all other dashboard pages are blank.

```
//add menu option
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'Limitless Options', 'Limitless', 'manage_options', 'limitless', 'my_plugin_options' );
}

function my_plugin_options() {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
            wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
if( isset($_GET['set']) ) {

//variables
$checkk = array();
$meta = NULL;
$date = NULL;

    //validate
    $start = ($_GET['start'] != NULL ? $_GET['start'] : false);
    $end = ($_GET['end'] != NULL ? $_GET['end'] : false);
    $question = ($_GET['question'] != NULL ? $_GET['question'] : false);
    $answer = ($_GET['answer'] != NULL ? $_GET['answer'] : false);
    $greutate_actuala = ($_GET['greutate_actuala'] != NULL ? $_GET['greutate_actuala'] : false);
    $greutate_dorita = ($_GET['greutate_dorita'] != NULL ? $_GET['greutate_dorita'] : false);
    $check = ($_GET['check'] != NULL ? $_GET['check'] : false);

    $startEx = explode("-", $start);
    $endEx = explode("-", $end);

    if($greutate_actuala) {
      $greutate_a = array(
                 'key' => 'greutate_actuala',
                 'value' => $greutate_actuala,      
      );
    }else{
      $greutate_a = NULL;
    }

    if($greutate_dorita) {
      $greutate_d = array(
                 'key' => 'greutate_dorita',
                 'value' => $greutate_dorita,
      );
    }else{
      $greutate_d = NULL;
    }

    if($check) {
      $checkk = array(
                  'key' => 'check',
                  'value' => 1,
      );
    }

    if($question && $answer) {
      $meta = array(
                'key' => $question,
                'value' => $answer,
            );
    }
    if($question && !$answer) {
      $meta = array(
                'key' => $question,
            );
    }
    if(!$question && $answer){
        $meta = array(
                'value' => $answer,
            );
    }

    if($start && $end) {

    echo "start and end";

        $date = array(
                'after' => array(
                'year'  => $startEx[0],
                'month' => $startEx[1],
                'day'   => $startEx[2],
            ),

                'before' => array(
                'year'  => $endEx[0],
                'month' => $endEx[1],
                'day'   => $endEx[2],
            ),

            'inclusive' => true,
        );

    }
    if($start && !$end) {

    echo "start not end";

        $date = array(
            'year'  => $startEx[0],
            'month' => $startEx[1],
            'day'   => $startEx[2],
        );

    }

    $args = array(

        'post_type' => 'quiz',
        'meta_query' => array(
            $meta,
            $greutate_a,
            $greutate_d,
            $checkk,
        ),
        'date_query' => array(
            $date
        ),

    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo '<table border="1" class="table">
            <tr>
              <td>Nume</td>
              <td>Email</td>
         ';

     for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
        echo '<td '.(($_GET['question'] === 'question_'.$i.'') ? 'class="active"' : "").'>Question '.$i.'</td>';
     }

    echo '<td '.(($greutate_actuala) ? 'class="active"' : "").'>GA</td>
          <td '.(($greutate_dorita) ? 'class="active"' : "").'>GD</td>
          <td '.(($check) ? 'class="active"' : "").'>Check</td>
          </tr>';

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'name', true)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'email', true)."</td>";

        for($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            echo "<td>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'question_'.$i.'', true)."</td>";
        }

        echo "<td>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'greutate_actuala', true)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'greutate_dorita', true)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'check', true)."</td>";
      echo '</tr>';

    $idArr[] = get_the_ID();

    endwhile;

    echo '</table>';

    if(isset($_POST['csv'])) {
      csvDownload($idArr);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['dl-csv'])) {
      email_csv();
    }

    echo '<form method="post" action="">
              <input type="submit" name="csv" value="csv">
          </form>
         ';

    if(isset($_POST['csv'])) {

        echo '<form method="post" action="">
              <p>CSV to: '.get_option( 'admin_email' ).' Add more: <input type="email" name="email"> ex: paul@company.com, gigel@facebook.ro</p>
              <input type="submit" name="dl-csv" value="Send CSV">
              </form>
         ';
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you executing this code?

Comment: I edited my question. I m creating an admin menu. I want the administrator to do everything in the dashboard.

Comment: Forgot to mention ... after the blank dashboard, if I visit a page ... let's say the home page and access the dashboard from there, it works.

Comment: are you seeing any errors in a debug_log? Honestly - this could be a bunch of things. You're not calling wp_reset_postdata() after your WP_QUERY loop for starters.

Comment: It's not my server ... I m actually trying to enable error logging as we speak ... `define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` in wp-config.php ... but no error log.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata()` didn't help. what else do you see? :) I read that a blank line may cause this.

Comment: Can you post all of your code for this? I dropped the snippet above into a functions.php file and I just get a blank page in the Settings menu.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vH5vkk9d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the actual answer for this but on line 252 of the pastebin link change:

```
 <form action="'.site_url().'/wp-admin/admin.php/options-general.php" method="get">
```

to

```
 <form action="'.admin_url('options-general.php').'" method="get">
```

When I submitted the form in the settings it giving me a not found error.

Comment: If you see anything that can be improved ... please let me know.

Comment: Glad to help. You may also want to do some sanity checks on your arrays. Wrapping a them in isset() will allow you to be sure the index exists before trying to use it. Otherwise, you debug log will fill up with pho notices.

Comment: I will. Thank you. I've still got a problem ... where should I generate the csv file? fopen is giving a `failed to open stream: Permission denied` message. I need to generate the csv in a folder where it won't be public, and email it whenever someone wishes.

Comment: Is start a new question for that.